# My emails keep getting messed up when lists are introduced

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the ending of my email gets messed up any time there's a list (or div, or blockquote) above it. If I remove the list, then the problem magically goes away. Everything is closed properly, everything is aligned properly, etc. So I'm at a loss - what am I doing wrong? Template below:

```
<div style="max-width: 600px !important; padding: 20px; background-color: #FFFFFF"><p style="color: #191C22;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin: 10px 0;padding: 0;mso-line-height-rule: exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;font-size: 16px;line-height: 150%;text-align: left; width: 100%;">Hi!&nbsp;<br>
  <br>
  Thanks for starting your application!<br><br>

  Give us a call at our number or you can email us with questions.
  <br><br>
  Thanks for your business!<br>
  <br>
  <ul></ul>
  Best,<br>
  Magenta & Co
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as a test to see what happens, try getting rid of all your BR's and having each parahgraph inside a set op P tags. That's the end of a P tag before your list and then a new P tag after the list. I suspect the problem originates in code that is not shown though.

Comment: use `table` instead of list, because email provider didn't support some tags.

Comment: Thanks all, I figured it out! Here's the answer (because I've read that XKCD too): I didn't have the appropriate styles in the DIV. By copying the styles (left alignment, font) from the paragraph and adding them to the DIV, everything came together perfectly.